# jquery input field change even when value is changed via jquery

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

I am attempting to capture when a text input field's value is changed.  I am using:

```
$("input[name=color]").change(function(){
```

This works if I type the new value in directly.  However, the value of the input field is being changed by jquery.  There are several of these fields, and I need to know when any have changed.  Is there a way to detect this change?

Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I'm not the one changing the value.  It's an addon that I would rather not modify in case I need to port it to another project.

**WORK-AROUND**

Ok, so you can't do what I wanted to do, but here is a work-around.  I just made an interval and changed my `change` event to an `each` event.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("input[name=color]").each(function(){ my code })
},100);
```

Comment: how are you changing it with JQuery.  I mean the code that is doing it.  Can't you just do something at the same time that the code is changing it?

Comment: I wish I could, but it is a color picker plugin that is changing the values.  I just want to apply the values as they change.

Comment: this workaround does the trick, not sure if it actually increase the page load time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to detect the changes done programmatically.

However you can trigger a `change` event whenever you modify its value.

```
$("input[name=color]").val("newValue").change();
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct since it does answer the question.  But I'm also posting my work-around in my code if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

When change the value by jquery you can fire the change event with jquery afterwards

```
$("input[name=color]").val('someValue').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't controlling the other jquery.  However, I found a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

No, onchange event will not be triggered when the value is changed using javascript. Alternatively you can call the onchange event when you change the value.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't controlling the other jquery.  However, I found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to track the value outside the scope of your listener

```
function foo () {
  var value = null;
  $("select#thingy").on("change", function (e) {
    let p = $(this).children("#choose-me").val();
    value = value === p ? null : p;
    $(this).val(value);
  });
}

$(function() {
  foo();
})
```